# Selenium user interface test inconsistently fails during ajax request

Tags: c#, ajax, selenium, coded-ui-tests

I'm making a selenium UI test in visual studio in c#, and it randomly breaks when an ajax request is made. During the test I enter a string into a text input, then find a different element and click on it, this is to make the the onblur event fire for the text input I just used. In the onblur event I make an ajax request that returns the information about the account just entered in the input. Everything works when I run the app, and it occasionally passes the UI test, but sometimes fails before the ajax gets completed (I pop up a toaster message on ajax success, I don't see this when it fails). The code is as follows:

```
IWebElement element = _Driver.FindElement(By.Id("RelationshipAccount"));
element.SendKeys("100006");

element = _Driver.FindElement(By.Id("RelationshipCity"));
element.Click();

_Wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Id("toaster")));
```

The test inconsistently passes/fails after the element.Click(); line. Any ideas on why this is happening or how to make it consistently pass?

Comment: Can you show us the stacktrace? There are several reason to error when click e.g. Stale element, element is not clickable yet.